# How to append chars to a textbox while typing in tinymce textarea until pressing ENTER?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a simple textbox and a textarea which is "tinymce-d".
I'd like to append characters that I type into tinymce to textbox contents until I press ENTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction of ShankarSangolis approch. Tinymce may be initialized for a textarea, but it is a contenteditable iframe while the textarea (or other init html element) becomes hidden. This is the correct way to do it. You need to call this code eigther on tinymce init or afterwards befor a user can type.

```
// the editorid equals the textarea id!
var editor = tinymce.get(editor_id) || tinymce.editors[0]; // use first tinymce editor if no editorid was provided
$(editor.getBody()).keyup(function(e){
   if(e.which != 13){
      $("textbox").val(this.value);
   }
});
```

Comment: I have used your code suggestion and made something that I included into tinymce init

Comment: At the end yes, but it's not exactly the code in above examples

Comment: hey, "your solution" equals mine regarding the idea and functionality!

Comment: Good, I've chosen your answer if that means something for you, I can't vote up at the moment as I'm starting here and don't have enough points

Comment: yes this means something to me - it is a token of honor and respect  given to me - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(e){
   if(e.which != 13){
      $("textbox").val(this.value);
   }
});
```

Comment: that might work for a simple textarea, but not for tinymce-ed one

Comment: @Shankar, I've tried it and it doesn't work of course as tinymce isn't textarea as Thariama said

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I'm using dugin tinymce init:

```
setup : function (theEditor) {
    theEditor.onKeyUp.add(
        function (theEditor, event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13) stop = true;
            if (stop == false) {
            var content = theEditor.getContent();
                $("#subject").val(content);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

stop is a global variable initialized before the init and then window.stop gets value when needed.

Comment: hey, "your solution" equals mine regarding the idea and functionality! You didn't cast one single vote on Stackoverflow - sooner or later people will refuse to answer your questions...